# C, save/read NULL with text file

Tags: c

I can't get rid of compiler warning "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" in following case:

```
    int sql_user(char** mysql_user_name, char** mysql_password, char** mysql_server, char **mysql_serverport, char** mysql_socket)
{
    int retval = -1;
    char **sub;
    char *contents;
    if(g_file_get_contents("mysqlsrv.def", &contents, NULL, NULL))
    {
        sub = g_strsplit(contents, "\n", -1);
        //here compiler warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

        *mysql_user_name  = sub[0];
        *mysql_password   = sub[1];
        *mysql_server     = sub[2];
        *mysql_serverport = sub[3];
        *mysql_socket     = sub[4];
        if (!strlen(sub[4])) *mysql_socket = NULL;
        retval = 0;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Additionaly, In sub[4] is empty string (""). Is here a way to save NULL instead to text file so it can be readed later as NULL without If (!strlen... condition?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: g_strsplit is declared in <gtk.h> and I use this function allaround my project from several files so I haven't any problem with returning data. Here is function call: sql_user(&mysql_user_name, &mysql_password, &mysql_server, &mysql_serverport, &mysql_socket);

Comment: If you use this from all around, you'll have a memory leak. I'm not up on gnome stuff, but a quick google (http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-file-get-contents) says you need to use g_free() on "contents" when you are done + g_strfreev() on the result of g_strsplit() when done. I'd suggest copying the values you need and calling those free methods inside your method above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like g_strsplit() is not known (declared), so the compiler is assuming the default return type of int.
I'd check your include files to make sure the one declaring g_strsplit() is included.

Comment: Yes, you right, thanks. I forget to include <gtk/gtk.h> in this file, but anyway function works (splits string on \n). How is this possible?

Comment: linker can still find the function definition, so it still works.

Comment: @user973238 very good question :) The fact it works at all is a weird historical feature of C - you should always try to compile with maximum warnings (-Wall -Werror), which would have warned that it couldn't find the function definiton.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no generic way to save a NULL to a text file, you'd need to decide on some way of encoding it in your config file.

In this particular case it'd simplest to just have `if(!strlen(sub[4]))` as you suggest.

If you want to have a config file format that supports NULLs I suggest using a markup langue or encoding format such as [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), [JSON](http://www.json.org/), [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), or maybe [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) that way you can use an existing library and avoid having to reinvent the wheel.

Since you're already Gnome lib the [Gnome config library](http://developer.gnome.org/libgnome/stable/libgnome-gnome-config.html) would be a good bet.

Comment: OK, If this is as you say, no problem. Thanx.

Comment: @user973238 you *could* save your config in a binary file (Protocol Buffers is primarily binary), but I *really* recommend that you don't. 1) It makes it hard / impossible to tweak by hand, 2) You'd be tying yourself to whatever library you choose to do this (so you wouldn't be able to use existing tools to generate/process the files), 3) For all of the above reasons and more the UNIX way is to use text files/streams wherever practical.

Comment: Hm, read/save binary files is not a problem and is portable. I often do that like fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, f);

Comment: Yes, Gnome is cross-platform.

Comment: Sure, fread() works, but you need to think at a higher level - what about byte ordering (big vs little endian), what if you want to process your input/output - eg sort, break into columns, search etc - all of these things are simple if you're handling text streams (using `sort`, `cut`, `grep`, respectively).  You should only use binary input/output where you're interfacing with an existing well defined format, and always use a library if there's one available.  Don't reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 1):

`g_strsplit` function is not declared in your source file and an implicit declaration of the function is made by the compiler. The implicit declaration is this one:

```
/* function that takes an unspecified number of parameters and retuns an int */
extern int g_strsplit();
```

To fix it, include the relevant headers for the `g_strsplit` function:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>
```